# What is the best algorithm for deterministic belief propagation?

Tags: graphs, graphical-model

Here is a simple example:

In a 3D space, if point A is the geocenter of a planet, point B is its north pole, and point C has a fixed latitude/longitude on the planet surface. Then the position of point C can be inferred from the position of A and B (using geodetic projection).

Now assuming that I have thousands of points in the space, their incomplete relations are in a big multipgraph. I would like to deduce the position of a point that is initially unknown. What is the best algorithm to search search through all its relations and try to deduce it?